# image and CSS color in ie 8 problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I m converting a template and everything is fine in ff. Problem is when i open converted template into internet explorer. I am using an image to make curve in navigation. That image's color matches with div's background color in ff but does not match in ie. another problem with ie is that back ground image of top navigation appears for a while and then disappears. I even tried a 1px image as background of div without any luck.

{note: problem1 is solved. it was because of ddroundies script that i m using to roundify divs.}

[image]

Comment: I know you've solved the dd_roundies problem, but you may want to consider looking into [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/) for an alternaitve solution to `border-radius` in IE. It's better than dd_roundies (IMHO), and it also supports other CSS3 features such as gradients.

Comment: First thought: embedded colour profiles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Color differences between images and html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154502/color-differences-between-images-and-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your image is a png, use a gif instead and see if it works. IE uses different png color profiles.

You can read more about the 'issue' here: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/png-gamma/

Comment: Good that you managed to find the issue. An alternative approach would be to make a 1px by 1px png in the blue colour and use it as the background for the div. Then both blues match as well.